# how to get highest 5 values from column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have products table with `name` and `no_of_sell` column..
I wanted to get highest 5 sold products based on `no_of_sell` column from products table.
how do i use it with query builder?

```
  $propular_products =  DB::table('users')
            ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
            ->select('products.*')   
            ->orderBy('products.no_of_sell', 'desc')              
            ->where('products.status','=','1') 
            ->paginate(5);
```

suppose `products` table:

```
name no_of_sell
 x     6
 y     9
 z     10
 t     23
 u     3
 h     11
 r      5
```

i wanted to find

```
products list of 5 max no_of_sell ie, x y z t h
```

Comment: you can use orderBy [https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it correctly in the column `no_of_sell` is a int. I should write it as follow :

```
$best_sell = DB::table('products')
             ->orderBy('no_of_sell', 'desc')
             ->limit(5)
             ->where('products.status','=','1') 
             ->paginate(4)
             ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 0):

```
$best_sell = DB::table('products')
         ->select('no_of_sell')   
         ->where('products.status','=','1')                       
         ->orderBy('no_of_sell', 'desc')
         ->paginate(4);
```

Comment: I used the desc but the problem is it doesn't show appropriate one. suppose no_of_sell has value of 7 9 10 12 15 ..if i want to get 4 data.it should return 9 10 12 15 but it returns 7 9 12 15

Answer (score 0):

```
$best_sell = DB::table('products')
        ->select() // your selection criteria 
        ->where('products.status','=','1') 
        ->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: it'll take highest 5 value only.